# how to create function subtract two dates?

Tags: sql, plsql

How can I return value for `expirydate-sysdate`? It gives me error. Can anyone help me?

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calc_remain_data(accountNumber account.account_number%TYPE)
    RETURN date IS
       CridetCardNo number(8); 
       expirydate date;
       res date;
    BEGIN

       SELECT credit_card_number into CridetCardNo 
       FROM c_relation 
       WHERE account_number = accountNumber ; 

       SELECT expiry_date into expirydate 
       FROM credit_card 
       WHERE credit_card_number = CridetCardNo;

       SELECT expirydate-SYSdate as result 
       from dual ; 

       return result  ;
    END;
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Why so many select statements

Answer (score 3):

You don't need two different SELECT statements, you can do that more efficiently with a single JOIN.

The result of subtracting one date from another is not a date but a number representing the number of days between those two dates. So you can't assign the result of `l_expirydate - sysdate` to a variable defined as `DATE`.

You didn't tell us what exactly that function should return. If "remaining data" is meant to be *days* then define l_result as `number` and change the function to return a number:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calc_remain_data(accountNumber account.account_number%TYPE)
  RETURN number --<< HERE
IS
  l_remaining_days number; --<< NOT a date!
BEGIN

   -- you can store the result of the calculation directly in the variable
   SELECT cc.expiry_date - sysdate
      INTO l_remaining_days
   FROM c_relation cr
     JOIN credit_card cc ON cc.credit_card_number = cr.credit_card_number
   WHERE account_number = accountNumber; 

   return l_remaining_days;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calc_remain_data(accountNumber account.account_number%TYPE)
RETURN number IS
   l_CreditCardNo number(8); 
   l_expirydate date;
   l_result number;
BEGIN

   SELECT credit_card_number INTO l_CreditCardNo 
   FROM c_relation 
   WHERE account_number = accountNumber ; 

   SELECT expiry_date INTO l_expirydate 
   FROM credit_card 
   WHERE credit_card_number = l_CreditCardNo;

   l_result := l_expirydate - sysdate;

   return l_result  ;
END;
```

Editted: change return type as commented

Comment: `l_expirydate - sysdate` returns a number, not a `DATE` so it can't be assigned to a variable defined as `date`

Comment: I knew something was off :D

Answer (score 0):

you can use **INTERVAL** data type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CALC_REMAIN_DATA (
   ACCOUNTNUMBER    ACCOUNT.ACCOUNT_NUMBER%TYPE)
   RETURN INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND--You can specify desired type here
IS
   CRIDETCARDNO   NUMBER (8);
   EXPIRYDATE     DATE;
   RES            DATE;
BEGIN
   SELECT CREDIT_CARD_NUMBER
     INTO CRIDETCARDNO
     FROM C_RELATION
    WHERE ACCOUNT_NUMBER = ACCOUNTNUMBER;

   SELECT EXPIRY_DATE
     INTO EXPIRYDATE
     FROM CREDIT_CARD
    WHERE CREDIT_CARD_NUMBER = CRIDETCARDNO;

   RETURN NUMTODSINTERVAL (EXPIRYDATE - SYSDATE, 'Day');--this function convert float number to interval type and has another version numtoyminterval
                                                 --^this specify the unit to calculate the interval
END;
```

actually date type wont help you much here, instead interval type helps to get difference value of two date in {Day Hour Minute Seconds Timestamp} or you can use another Interval type Year to Month which calculates value in {Year Month}